# string.Format does not made alignment with fixed width

Tags: c#, printing, receipt

This is my function to print a receipt for order, print is working but my problem is that print does not made a aligned records. i have attached a screen shot of output at the bottom please tell me what i do so output make good.

```
private void PrintReceipt(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
    {
        //Graphics g = this.CreateGraphics();
        Graphics graphic = e.Graphics;
        Font font = new Font("Courier", 8);
        Font Heading = new Font("Courier", 10);
        float fontHeight = font.GetHeight();
        int startX = 10;
        int startY = 10;
        int offset = 40;

        int receipt_w = 400;
        //int receipt_h = 0;

        string company_name = "Welcome to Arslan Medicose";
        string company_address = "Kohenoor One Jaranwala road faisalbad";
        string company_phone = "Phone:+9233898937";

        string developer_str = "Developed by: virk";
        string developer_contact = "Phone:+923338989937";

        string underLine = "-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------";


        SizeF size = graphic.MeasureString(company_name, Heading);
        graphic.DrawString(company_name, Heading, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), (receipt_w - size.Width) / 2, startY);

        //offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;
        size = graphic.MeasureString(company_address, Heading);
        graphic.DrawString(company_address, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), (receipt_w - size.Width) / 2, startY + offset);

        offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;

        size = graphic.MeasureString(company_phone, Heading);
        graphic.DrawString(company_phone, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), (receipt_w - size.Width) / 2, startY + offset);

        offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;

        graphic.DrawString(underLine, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);

        offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;

        int total_rows = cart_pro_gv.RowCount;
        int recs = 1;

        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in cart_pro_gv.Rows) {

            if (recs < total_rows)
            {
                string pn = (null != row.Cells[1].Value) ? row.Cells[1].Value.ToString().Trim() : String.Empty;
                string pq = (null != row.Cells[2].Value) ? row.Cells[2].Value.ToString().Trim() : String.Empty;
                string pp = (null != row.Cells[3].Value) ? row.Cells[3].Value.ToString().Trim() : String.Empty;
                string ppt = (null != row.Cells[4].Value) ? row.Cells[4].Value.ToString().Trim() : String.Empty;


                string pline = string.Format("{0,-40}|{1,-15}|{2,-15}|{3,-15}", pn, pq, pp, ppt);
                //string pline = string.Format("{0}|{1}|{2}|{3}", pn.PadRight(30), pq.PadRight(30), pp.PadRight(30), ppt.PadRight(30));

                /*int padding = 3;
                int maxCol0width = pn.Length;
                int maxCol1width = pq.Length;
                int maxCol2width = pp.Length;
                int maxCol3width = ppt.Length;

                string fmt0 = "{0,-" + (maxCol0width + padding) + "}";
                string fmt1 = "{1,-" + (maxCol1width + padding) + "}";
                string fmt2 = "{2,-" + (maxCol2width + padding) + "}";
                string fmt3 = "{3,-" + (maxCol3width + padding) + "}";

                string fmt = fmt0 + fmt1 + fmt2 + fmt3;

                string pline = string.Format(fmt, pn, pq, pp, ppt);*/


                graphic.DrawString(pline, font, Brushes.Black, startX, startY + offset);
                offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;
            }
            recs++;
        }

       // offset = offset + (int)fontHeight + 5;

        graphic.DrawString(underLine, font, Brushes.Black , startX, startY + offset);

        offset = offset + 10;
        string total_paying = "Net Total: " + cart_total_label.Text;
        graphic.DrawString(total_paying, font, new SolidBrush(Color.Black), startX, startY + offset);
    }
```

Here is output that I am getting:

[image]

Comment: The alignment issue is being caused by the varying length of the strings on the left. Notice how the "Perasilamole" string is the shortest string, and so the numbers are farthest to the left. I'm not quite sure how your code works, but maybe you could vary the number of spaces after the medicine name based on the length of the medicine name?

Comment: I was going to suggest String.PadRight but it looks like you tried it already. what problem did you have using it?

Comment: mark i am confusing what happening with it why it take this view.

Comment: I understand, just trying to find out why you commented out the String.PadRight lines. If you know the length of your fields and use a Monospaced font like you are it should work.

Comment: The font shown is not Courier and not monospaced.

Comment: Thanks CodeCaster you are right. problem is solved by your comment